# Create array of comboboxes on tabcontrol1

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I need to create 10 array comboboxes on `tab2` of `tabcontrol1`. I'm not aware of how to create those in tab2 specifically. How to do it.

```
Private Sub CreateComboArray(ByVal number As Integer, ByVal container As Control)

    Dim position As Integer = 7
    Dim combo As ComboBox
    For i As Integer = 0 To number - 1

        combo = New ComboBox()
        combo.Name = "combo" + i.ToString()
        combo.Height = 22
        combo.Width = 90
        combo.text = i.ToString()
        container.Controls.Add(combo)
        combo.Left = position
        position += 95
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    CreateComboArray(10, TabControl1)
End Sub
```

Comment: pass `tab2.controls` as the container

Comment: ...err  would actually be `tab2` - the actual container you want to add to.

Comment: yes. You're right. now it works. Thanks